# How is PyTorch's Class BCEWithLogitsLoss exactly implemented?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, implementation, loss

According to [the PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html), the advantage of the class `BCEWithLogitsLoss()` is that one can use the

> log-sum-exp trick for numerical stability.

If we use the class `BCEWithLogitsLoss()` with the parameter `reduction` set to `None`, they have a formula for that:

[image: Loss]

I now simplified the terms, and obtain after some lines of calculation:

[image]

I was curious to see whether this is the way how the [Source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/loss.html#BCEWithLogitsLoss) does it, but I couldn't find it.. The only code they have is this:

[Code for BCEWithLogitsLoss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa0pd.png)

Answer (score 15):

`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` is actually just cross entropy loss that comes inside a sigmoid function. It may be used in case your model's output layer is not wrapped with sigmoid. Typically used with the raw output of a single output layer neuron.

Simply put, your model's output say `pred` will be a raw value. In order to get probability, you will have to use `torch.sigmoid(pred)`. (To get actual class labels, you need `torch.round(torch.sigmoid(pred))`.) However, you don't need to do anything like that (i.e take sigmoid) when you use `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`. Here you just have to do the following-

```
criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
loss = criterion(pred, target) # pred is just raw nn output
```

Hence, coming to implementation part, criterion accepts two torch tensors - one being the raw nn outputs, the other being the true class labels, then wraps the first using sigmoid - for each element in the tensor and then calculates Cross Entropy loss `(-(target*log(sigmoid(pred)))` for each pair and reduces it to mean.

Answer (score 11):

All the pytorch functional code is implemented in C++. The source code for the implementation is located [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c64e006fc399d528bb812ae589789d0365f3daf4/aten/src/ATen/native/Loss.cpp#L214).

The pytorch implementation computes `BCEWithLogitsLoss` as

[image]

where `t_n` is simply `-relu(x)`. The use of `t_n` here is basically a clever way to avoid taking exponentials of positive values (thus avoiding overflow). This can be made more clear by  substituting `t_n` into the `l_n` which yields the following equivalent expression

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [C++ implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c64e006fc399d528bb812ae589789d0365f3daf4/aten/src/ATen/native/Loss.cpp#L214) they use this function in the end:

```
static inline at::Tensor apply_loss_reduction(const at::Tensor& unreduced, int64_t reduction) {
    if (reduction == at::Reduction::Mean) {
      return unreduced.mean();
    } else if (reduction == at::Reduction::Sum) {
      return unreduced.sum();
    }
    return unreduced;
  }
```

As you can see in [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) they use mean reduction by default.